# Extract server IP from the group in the inventory file

Tags: ansible

I have the following `inventory` file:

```
[group_01]
g01_h01         ansible_ssh_host='10.1.0.1'
g01_h01         ansible_ssh_host='10.1.0.2'

[group_02]
g02_h01         ansible_ssh_host='10.2.0.1'
g02_h01         ansible_ssh_host='10.2.0.2'

[group_03:children]
group_01
group_02

[group_03:vars]
fst_group2={{groups['group_02'][0]}}
snd_group1={{groups['group_01'][1]}}
```

I would like that in my `playbook` variables had the following values:

```
fst_group2=10.2.0.1
snd_group1=10.1.0.2
```

Instead I get:

```
fst_group2=g02_h01
snd_group1=g01_h02
```

Any ideas, a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very strange task indeed... Anyway,

`groups` variable – is a list of hosts, which are `g01_h01`, `g01_h02`, etc.
To achieve what you expect, you may use this:

```
[group_03:vars]
fst_group2={{hostvars[groups['group_02'][0]]['ansible_ssh_host']}}
snd_group1={{hostvars[groups['group_01'][1]]['ansible_ssh_host']}}
```

And keep in mind that `ansible_ssh_host` is deprecated in favor of `ansible_host`.